# Permissions for mounted NFS share?

Tags: permissions, nfs

I have two linux boxes, one is Ubuntu 11.10 that I have an nfs share set up with, and the other is Ubuntu 12.04 that I have mounted the nfs share at.

`/etc/exports` on the 11.10 box looks like:

```
/share           192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,all_squash,insecure)
```

and the 12.04 box `/etc/fstab` looks like:

```
192.168.1.10:/share /import nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

The share mounts fine, and I can see the files. The problem is that I cannot create new files in the mounted share.

```
$ mkdir /import/test 
mkdir: cannot create directory `/import/test': Read-only file system
```

I am pretty sure it is something on the 12.04 box that is not set right, since I can mount the nfs mount on my mac and can create folders and files.

So how to allow write access to the NFS share on the 12.04 box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the permissions of /import folder (as you mentioned 12.04 box) so that you can have write access.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and now I feel silly. The only I would add is that I add to run `sudo umount /import` to unmount the share first, and then change the permission.