# Nautilus cannot write into 1st directory of a NFS share

Tags: permissions, mount, nautilus, nfs, nas

I have a synology NAS.
On the client I create the directory :

```
mkdir /media/feydreva/download
chown -R feydreva /media/feydreva
chmod 777 /media/feydreva/download
```

I can mount my NFS without any issue :

```
sudo mount -t nfs 10.2.1.3:/volume1/download /media/feydreva/download
```

I can create file and directories into it

```
mkdir /media/feydreva/download/AAA 
touch /media/feydreva/download/aaaa.test
```

But, when I use ubuntu explorer (nautilus), annd I go to that directory, I cannot create new folder. I cannot save file into it.
I can go into the AAA directory, and here I can create folder and save file.

Interresting thing is that with Libreoffice, I can create a directory and save a file into /media/feydreva/download/ ,only nautilus cannot.

```
id : uid=1026(feydreva) gid=1000(feydreva) groupes=1000(feydreva),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),128(sambashare)

 getfacl : suppression du premier « / » des noms de chemins absolus
# file: media/feydreva/download
# owner: feydreva
# group: feydreva
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

so today (02022018) : 
I tried changing the uid of "feydreva" my PC, to match the one of "feydreva" on the NAS. So i changee the uid to 1026.
I did a 
    sudo chown -R feydreva:feydreva /media/feydreva/download
I still have the same exact issue: cannot write on /media/feydreva/download, but can in /media/feydreva/download/AAAA using nautilus, works fine in console/bsh or libreoffice..

Any idea or suggestions ?

Comment: `/media/feydreva/` is further up the tree than your mount point at `/media/feydreva/download` so if your testing your ability to read and write to NFS your using the wrong directory and as such your question is unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/143905/permissions-for-mounted-nfs-share?rq=1

Comment: Could you please try to change the access permissions *after* you mount the (remote) file system? When a directory is used as a mount point its properties, including access permissions, are overridden by those of the root directory of the mounted tree.

Comment: OK, sorry for the confusion,

I can create file and directories into it using a console /shell
>mkdir /media/feydreva/downnload/AAA 
>touch /media/feydreva/download/aaaa.test
but I cannnot savee file, nor create directories using the file explorer Nautilus.

Comment: @DavidFoerster : I did change the permission of the directory of the mount point after the mount is done, and I have same results.

the funnny thing is that it is just with Nautilus
I just tried creating a document with Libreoffice and save it, I can save it in the directory.
I also tried to create a direcotry into the mount with libreoffice and it works.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `id` and `getfacl /media/feydreva/download`? Thanks.

Comment: done. I also tried changing uid to get matching one... same issue.

Comment: any idea ? :) I m kind of stuck there.
i gave the download exemple, bbut it is same for all shared directory ..
Cannot it be a problem with nautilus ?  is there a specific forum for nautilus questions ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not merely a bug in Nautilus.  I use nemo as my regular file manager and it exhibit the same behavior.

When I use PCManFM, it works.

PCManFM uses a different type of graphic library. I suspect the problem is more on the gnome side.

Answer (score 1):

[3 years later...]

Having exactly the same issue (/home folder mounted in NFS from a Synology NAS, from terminal or PCManFM all working ok, but couldn't create folder on /home/<myuser> from Nautilus or Thunar, only on subfolders )

After digging further, I found the issue opened on Nautilus side:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/884

What did the trick for me was the last answer of DirkSchmidt to create a custom permission on the corresponding /home shared folder from Synology UI, with all permissions ticked, including delete.
After logging out, unmounting /home, then remounting and logging in again, I could create folder from Nautilus and Thunar directly in /home/<myuser>

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my NAS synology, and an NFS mount.
The mount point is root:root, and is not to be writen by users. It's necessary to create other folders under this point, using sudo. Then, it's possible for users to read and write in these subfolders. But not with NAUTILUS !
So, I installed an other file manager (PCManFM), and with PCManFM, it's possible to write in these subfolders.

Conclusion : this is a bug of NAUTILUS !!!

Comment: how to you report a bug for nautilus ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Caja (MATE) and an NFSv4 server exporting:

```
/export (ro,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,crossmnt,fsid=0)
/export/data (rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/export/downloads (rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/export/home (rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

Where data, downloads, home are bind mounts to directories on a single filesystem.

Adding a unique fsid to each entry solves it for me.

```
/export (ro,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,crossmnt,fsid=0)
/export/data (rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000, fsid=1)
/export/downloads (rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000, fsid=2)
/export/home (rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000, fsid=3)
```

Comment: Because I am using a laptop thus I only mount to my Synology when I am at home.  I prefer to use "mount" command in a shell script and mount it manually.